# Why inject the entire DbContext instead of just the necessary DbSets?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, anti-patterns

I've seen a lot of projects whether the entire DbContext is injected in a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyDbContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public void DoStuff()
    {
         dbContext.MyTable.Select(x => x...)
    }
}
```

Why not do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(DbSet<MyType> myTypes)
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public void DoStuff()
    {
         myTypes.Select(x => x...)
    }
}
```

I find #2 makes it more clear as to what data exactly the object needs to operate. It makes unit testing especially more clear as the dependencies are obvious from the constructor. Otherwise, you have to inspect the implementation of the method to find out what data it needs exactly so you can setup your test properly.

So why is #1 the norm?

(P.S. sorry for bad tags but it seems the tag system is broken atm)

Comment: Because you *need* the `DbContext` to do anything useful like saving changes to the db. Also, because injecting 20 `DbSet<T>` to DI is much more painful than just injecting the `DbContext`. And probably many other things too

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why can't SaveChanges be an extension method to make up for it not being on the DbSet? And for registration, one could just register all public properties that are assignable to DbSet on the context. So no need to manually add all the DbSets in Di.

Comment: Well, using an extension method would only hide the dependency on the DbContext and make testing much harder

Comment: See [DbContext lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/). Note Important section.

Comment: I disagree with most of the opinions here and prefer to see individual repositories (DbSet in EF terminology) being injected rather than the entire db context. E.g. 1. the business layer does not know when the transaction is complete - it only knows when it's job is done. 2. who writes a single class that updates 20 repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally developers write unit tests to test business use cases and the data access layer should not contain any logic and that's why people use [Repository Pattern](https://www.thinktocode.com/2018/01/08/repository-pattern) to hide the implementation of the data access layer.

> Otherwise, you have to inspect the implementation of the method to
> find out what data it needs exactly so you can setup your test
> properly.

`MyDbContext` and `DbSet<MyType>` are related to data access and when you try to implement unit tests for `DoStuff` method, you should not consider the implementation of query for writing test and the only thing you need is mocking `MyDbContext` or `DbSet<MyType>`. Also when use concrete class as a dependency, you violate [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), and that is why you have to look at the implementation of `DoStuff` method to find out what data and where the data comes from.

Comment: It could be an interface... IDbSet interface or something. And I think a lot of people are against using the repository pattern with EF: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/

Comment: `IDbSet` still is a kind of repository, it hides the implementation of the actual `DbSet<T>`, the whole idea is using abstraction instead of using concrete implementation.

Comment: `DbContext` *is* a Repository. `DbSet<T>` *is* a Unit of Work. I cringe everytime someone suggest such a useless abstraction. There's basically no benefit except for the extremely rare scenarios where a company might actually decide to spend thousands on a project just to get rid of EF. I've seen this hiding of EF mostly by developers who can't realize how to properly test EF and make insanely difficult to follow architectures

Comment: `DbSet<T> is a Unit of Work`, When I add to `DbSet<MyType>.Add(myType)` all data are persisted? `DbSet`s are repositories and `UoF` is applied when `SaveChanges` method is called. [`DbContext` is a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f5ab73d7745bbe7ed684b09d5d8ea35e4f90a9df/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L24). However, you could my article about paying of mocking `DbSet` and it's kind of leaky abstraction https://dev.to/moesmp/leaky-abstraction-and-clean-architecture-template-7nf

Answer (score 0):

Because the "Save" is on the dbcontext, not the child collections.

"**SaveChangesAsync**" as the most important one.  But others listed below.

```
        int saveChangesAsyncValue = await this.myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
```

Framework:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-5.0

Others (core):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-5.0

You should really focus having unit tests on your BUSINESS LOGIC.  And subtly, this also means.

1. Stop putting (any) business logic in your data layer.  (and its kissing cousin, stop putting business logic in your presentation layer).

You should inject a (mock) of your datalayer into your business logic classes.

Having said that, EF InMemoryDatabase has blurred the lines a little bit.

But that does not avoid having to have the "myDbContext" available.